# Outlook 2013 html email adding margin to right & bottom of background image

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, email-client

I cannot figure out why it's adding margin to the side and bottom of the background image and therefore cropping the image. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
   <td background="http://s10.postimg.org/rcw5jrw3d/header.jpg" bgcolor="#230f0e" width="600" height="400" valign="top">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:400px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://s10.postimg.org/rcw5jrw3d/header.jpg" color="#230f0e" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
  <div>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td mc:edit="title" style="color:white; font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:32px; padding-left:12px; padding-top:8px">Samson Bar &amp; Cafe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td mc:edit="price" align="right" style="color:#fb0000; font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:27px; padding-right:12px; padding-top:198px">Only 999$, limited offer!</td>

  </tr>
</table>
  </div>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td mc:hideable align="center" bgcolor="#230f0e" style="text-align:center; background-color:#230f0e; padding:13px"><img mc:edit="image-area" src="http://placehold.it/550x350"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td mc:edit="text-area" mc:hideable="" bgcolor="#000000" style="color:white; font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:12px;;background-color:#000000; padding:13px">Lorem Ipsum is a nice simplydummy text ot the printing and the a typesetting industry. Lorem 
Ipsum is a nice simplydummy text ot the printing and the a typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum 
is a nice simplydummy text ot the printing and the a typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is a nic 
simplydummy text ot the printing and the a typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is a nice simply
dummy text ot the printing and the a typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is a nice simplydummy
text ot the printing and the a typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is a nice simplydummy text ot  
the printing and the a typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is a nice simplydummy text ot the pri
ing and the a typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is a nice simplydummy text ot the printing an 
the a typesetting industry. Lorem aIpsum is a nice simplydummy text ot the printing and the a 
typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum ais a nice simplydummy text ot the printing and the a types
tting industry. Lorem Ipsum is a nica simplydummy text ot the printing and the a typesetting in
ustry. Lorem Ipsum is a nice simplyadummy text ot the printing and the a typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is a nice simplydummya text ot the printing and the a typesetting industry.Lorem 
Ipsum is a nice simplydummy text ot  a the printing and the a typesetting industry. </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td background="http://s10.postimg.org/4zoewyv5l/footer.jpg" bgcolor="#682204" width="600" height="150" valign="top">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:150px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://s10.postimg.org/4zoewyv5l/footer.jpg" color="#682204" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
  <div><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:white; padding-left:15px; padding-top:10px">Copyright © 2014. Samson Bar &amp; Cafe.<br>
      All rights reserved.</td>
    <td align="center" style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:white; padding-top:10px">Follow Us on</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" rowspan="3"><a href="#"><img src="http://s15.postimg.org/gz5h8efzb/facebook.png" width="41" height="40" alt="Facebook"></a>&nbsp;<a href="#"><img src="http://s15.postimg.org/vwj06izjb/linkedin.png" width="41" height="41" alt="LinkedIn"></a>&nbsp;<a href="#"><img src="http://s15.postimg.org/h0ff1tht3/twitter.png" width="41" height="40" alt="Twitter"></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:white; padding-left:15px; padding-top:15px">Our mailing address: <a href="#">xxxxx@xxxxx.com</a></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2" style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:white; padding-left:15px; padding-top:15px"><a href="*|UNSUB|*">Unsubscribe from this list</a> | <a href="*|UPDATE_PROFILE|*">Update subscription preferences</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This seems to only happen when viewing in the Outlook 2013 email summary, and not opening the email as a new window.

Here is an image showing what's happening - [problem](http://s11.postimg.org/fwiaoxpfn/Samson_email_image.png)

Answer (score 0):

weird, i just ran your html through litmus and it looked the same in chrome as it does on outlook '13...

try changing `fill type="tile"` to `"frame"`?

other than that my best guess is that mailchimp has some pre-processing going on with your `mc:xxx` handles. you may want to contact them about this.

[Litmus Test](https://litmus.com/pub/0a3e41c/screenshots)